# how tailed recursion inside loop works?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to understrand recursion, and i am very new to recursion.
Considering the example given above there is a recursive call inside a for loop.

program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#define n 2
using namespace std;
int k = 0;
void nontailrec(int x) {
if(x == n) {
    return;
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    cout<< i << " "<< x <<endl;
    nontailrec(x+1);
}
}
int main() {
nontailrec(k);
return 0;
}
```

Now understanding the flow of the program what i figured out the flow is:

```
main();
nontailrec(0);
0 == 2 ?
<<0 0
nontailrec(1);
1 == 2 ?
<<0 1             
nontailrec(2);    
2 == 2 ?           
return void            
<<1 1
<<1 0

end of program
```

but the actual output is:

```
0 0
0 1
1 1
1 0
0 1
1 1
```

instead of

```
0 0
0 1
1 1
1 0
```

how the last two lines of output came, and what's the exact flow of program?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions.
In particular, `return` does not return to the initial top-level call, only to the immediate caller.
That is, terminating a recursion is not like exiting a loop.

Supposing you had one unique function for each `x`, your program would be equivalent to this:

```
void nontailrec_2() {
}

void nontailrec_1() {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        cout<< i << " "<< 1 <<endl;
        nontailrec_2();
    }
}

void nontailrec_0() {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        cout<< i << " "<< 0 <<endl;
        nontailrec_1();
    }
}

int main()
{
    nontailrec_0();
}
```

I'm sure you can follow the flow in this.